# AS3 - Reset Loader's Animation

Tags: actionscript-3, frame, reset, loader

I need to make it so that I go to frame 0 on a loader's animation. I have gone to Google, and searched on how to do this, but nothing shows up that's related. It should be possible, because I have seen it done before, but I just haven't found anything on how to do it.

Is there any way to reset the animation, or go to a specific frame?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) any code?

Comment: I've tried the commands stop(), and gotoAndStop(), but it's a loader, so it wont work. I've also tried converting it like this MovieClip(loader).gotoAndStop(0), and that will also not work.

Answer (score 0):

are you using `gotoAndPlay(0)`?

if so, that might be your problem. Frames count starts at 1 not 0, so it should be `gotoAndPlay(1)` if you want to start from beginning.

---

the way I handle externally loaded content is through an SwfLoad class from casaLib :
http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_load_SwfLoad.html

you can download casalib through http://casalib.org/

Note that this will only work if you have control over the file that you are loading

Int the file that is being loaded make sure you set a class name (linkage ID) for the movie clip you are trying to load.

```
//load your asset file:
this._swfLoad = new SwfLoad("myExternalLib.swf");


//and create the asset:
var externalAsset:DisplayObject = this._swfLoad.createClassByName("RedBox");
```

you can create more of these objects when you need to reload.

the first link shows full example

Comment: I have tried that, but since it is a Loader, it won't do it. Is there a way I can convert it into a MovieClip?

Comment: I getcha now... the thing you're trying to do is not that easy this way.  I'll update the answer with more info.